# How to add insert into and log on pdo

Tags: mysql, forms, pdo, insert, insert-into

I have an sql to add over 100 field to mysql database. I want to include coding for PDO to avoid this sql injection thing but, i'm new to all of this and really I do not know how nor truly understand it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My form has over 100 fields. I have no knowledge of how to do this. Thank you in advance.
Here's the code.

```
    <html>

<body>
<?php
>if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //Variables for connecting to your database.
    //These variable values come from your hosting account.
    $hostname = "hostname";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "dbname";
    $mystuff = array(  "tenant_lname","tenant_fname","tenant_mname","ssn","dl_number","dl_state","birthday","tenant_hphone","tenant_wphone","tenant_cphone","curr_street","curr__unit","curr_city","curr_state","curr_zip","how_long_from","how_long_to","last_rent_mnt","last_rent_amt","own_man_name","own_man_tel","curr_reason","pre_street","pre_unit","pre_city","pre_state","pre_zip","pre_from","pre_to","pre_last_rent","pre_amt","pre_owner","pre_owner_tel","pre_reason","sec_pre_street","sec_pre_unit","sec_pre_city","sec_pre_state","sec_pre_zip","sec_pre_from","sec_pre_to","sec_pre_last_paid_mnt","sec_pre_amt","sec_pre_owner","sec_pre_owner_tel","sec_pre_reason","curr_emp_name","curr_emp_add","curr_emp_phone","curr_emp_pos","curr_emp_bus_type","curr_emp_sup","curr_emp_from","curr_emp_to","curr_emp_salary","pre_emp_name","pre_emp_add","pre_emp_phone","pre_emp_pos","pre_emp_bus_type","pre_emp_sup_name","pre_emp_from","pre_emp_to","pre_emp_salary","move_date","addntl_occ_name","addntl_occ_age","addntl_occ_relation","addntl_ft","addntl_pt","addntl_occ1_name","addntl_occ1_age","addntl_occ1_relation","addntl_occ1_ft","addntl_occ1_pt","addntl_occ2_name","addntl_occ2_age","addnt2_occ1_relation","addntl_occ2_ft","addntl_occ2_pt","addntl_occ3_name","addntl_occ3_age","addntl_occ3_relation","addntl_occ3_ft","addntl_occ3_pt","credit_yes","credit_no","det_yes","det_no","evict_yes","evict_no","bnkry_yes","bnkry_no","fel_yes","fel_no","pet_yes","pet_no","pet_numb","pet_type","furn_yes","furn_no","ins_cov_yes","ins_cov_no","ints_yes","ints_no","ints_type","smoke_yes","smoke_no","occ_smoke_yes","occ_smoke_no","explain_smoke","bnk_name","bnk_add","checking","checking_bal","saving","saving_bal","bnk_name1","bnk_add1","checking1","checking_bal1","saving1","saving_bal1","other_income","credit_name","credit_add","credit_city","credit_acct","credit_bal","credit_payment","credit_name1","credit_add1","credit_city1","credit_acct1","credit_bal1","credit_payment1","credit_acct2_name","credit_add2","credit_city2","credit_acc2","credit_bal2","credit_payment2","credit_acc3_name","credit_acc3_add","credit_acc3_city","credit_acc3_number","credit_acc3_bal","credit_acc3_payment","emer_contact_name","emer_contact_add","emer_relation","emer_phone","reg_owner_yes","reg_owner_no","reg_who","vehicle_year","vehicle_make","vehicle_model","vehicle_color","vehicle_license","veh_state","vehicle2_year","vehicle2_make","vehicle2_model","vehicle2_color","vehicle2_license","veh2_state");


    $sql_values=array();
    foreach($mystuff as $fieldname) {
        /* do validation! */

        $sql_values[$fieldname] = "'" . mysql_real_excape_stiring($_POST[$fieldname]) . "'";
    }


    $con = mysql_connect("$hostname","$username","$password");
    if (!$con){
        die ("Can not connect:" . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("dbname",$con);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO dbname (".implode(',', $mystuff).") VALUES (" . implode(',', $sql_values) . ")";

    mysql_query($sql,$con);

    mysql_close($con);
}


foreach($mystuff as $fieldname) {
    echo "...an input field...";
}

?>



</body>
```

Comment: Well, where are your attempts with using PDO? I only see the old mysql extension of php getting used. Please read the documentation about PDO and look at the examples. Then certainly people will be happy to help with specific issues you run into!

Comment: Everything is explained in the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info): either how to log in and how to create a long insert query